# Query for fetching data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I am having following tables

```
 spam (element_id, spam_table,spam_by,add_date)
```

here (element_id,spam_by) is primary key
and spam_by is foreign key depends on id of user

```
user(id,fname,lname)
```

id is  primary key

```
profile_pic(pic_id,profile_p,userid)
```

userid is foreign key depends on id of user

```
comments( comment_id, comment_on, commented_by, comment_date, comment)
```

comments_id is primary key, comment_on is foreign key depends on id of elements
 commented_by  foreign key depends on id of user

```
 elements(id,name)
```

id is primary key

from the above table.
I want to fetch following details from above tables

```
 commented userid, name,pic,comment,commemt on element,spam userid, name,pic
```

Comment: Please check your wanted detail columns, they don't correspond to the tables you specified.."commented", or "pic" is in no table

Comment: what is `commented`, is that your new table ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start to look into join and join tables on userid.

```
 SELECT data you want
 FROM first table to join
 INNER JOIN secondtable
 ON first table userid = secondtable userid JOIN third table
 ON first table userid = thirdtable userid
 JOIN fourth table
 ON first table userid = fourth table userid
```

And so on until included everything you need.
DONT forget to give each table an alias

It is done like firsttable alias
You then query your table like this
alias.userid

Comment: There are many answer telling people where to start?!  Anyeay edited my answer formatting is due to the fact I editing from my cell phone.

Comment: @Suggestion should be kept put in Comments, though, anyway removed my -1 and added a +1 though, for your complete answer

Comment: Thanks Sashi! And your right, I will keep suggestions in comments from now on :)

Comment: this is general answer which will work for fetching data from multiple tables